# How my Sprite rotate(smooth rotation) of given angle from the current position in andEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

Currently i am creating a game demo application in android using andEngine version 1.

Currently my sprite is rotated with the angle as shown below code

```
 aircraft.setRotation((float) rotationAngle);
```

but my sprite is rotated from  its initial position every times but i want to do it from its current position not its initial position .Because in my game application sprite rotated with different angles repeatedly(many times). so its looks like very bad ! (as got jerk every time)so i wants smooth rotation of my sprite how can i do it ?

I also used for the smooth rotation with this code but still i did not get smooth rotation ..?

// this is for become smooth rotation of aircraft

for (int i = 0; i <= rotationAngle; i++) {

```
_aircraft.setRotation((float) i);
```

}

Comment: If you don't find desire answer then provide more information what you want to say.

Comment: my sprite image is horizontal and if i  give rotation angle between 0 to 360 then sprite rotate every time with its initial position (in my case from horizontal) whether my sprite currently is in vertical though its take rotation from the initial position (from horizontal).  so i want my sprite should rotate from its current position not its initial position .i think now its clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I understand your question you have to use

```
aircraft.setRotationCenter(pCenterX,pCenterY);
```

Using this method you can rotate your object at desire position you want. Default point of rotation is centre of your sprite.

Comment: i would like to say one thing my sprite(aircraft) is continuously running so  we can not  provide rotation center to the sprite other wise it will go back to the rotation point and then rotate so its look very bad.

Comment: You have to use rotation modifier in which you have to provide your current angle and your desire angle to which you want to rotate so it start rotate from current angle to desire angle. If you want this action to be continue then user loop modifier.

Comment: If you found my answer as correct then mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If i read your question correctly this is what you want:
Each time you call "setRotation" you want the rotation to take into account the current rotation plus the amount of additional rotation specified by the "rotationAngle" variable.
If that is the case, then the solution is simple.

Instead of:

```
 aircraft.setRotation((float) rotationAngle);
```

Use:

```
 aircraft.setRotation((float) (aircraft.getRotation()+rotationAngle));
```

In this way, you can rotate the airplane by a set angle (the rotationAngle) at any time and it will add that amount to the airplane's current rotation.

Comment: if we done above then what happen i explain here           if in my case aircraft.getRotation() + rotationAngle = 90 then aircraft first move its current position (like horizontal ) and then set to the 90th angle if this done repeatedly then it looks like every time plane get a jerk (to set 0 to 90th angle) so its not suitable.